# Can't install 'usethis' package

Tags: r, install.packages, r-usethis

I'm using R-4.1.1 and the last version of Rstudio.

My goal is to use the `ggradar` package but I cannot install it with `install.packages` because:

> le package ‘ggradar’ is not available for this version of R

So I would like to install the application like this:

```r
devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar", dependencies=TRUE)
```

I managed to install `devtools` but when I try to:

```r
library(devtools)
```

there is this error:

> **Error: le package ‘usethis’ nécessaire pour ‘devtools’, mais est introuvable**

When I trying to install devtools with

```
install.packages("devtools",dependencies =TRUE)
```

it doesn't work. So finally, I try to install the package `usethis`

```r
install.packages("usethis")
```

but I can't do it: I have a big error which ends with:

> **Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status**

Can you help me please?

Comment: What is your operating system ? Mac OS ?

Comment: You need to figure out why `usethis` doesn't install. Is there any other input or just this warning? Basti has a great idea, we need to know the OS first. In case you're on a nix based system, there is a chance you are missing some system libraries which you'll need to install before proceeding with installing an R package. For example, this package imports curl, which is always a PITA to install.

Comment: My operating system is Windows @Basti

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason for your case, but things like  this can happen as a result of an inconsistent package set. It is in general a good idea to update installed packages before installing new ones.

As you have seen, package `usethis` depends on `devtools`, see:  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=usethis that also shows that `usethis` **is** availabe for **R** 4.1.1.

In inconsistency already happened, i.a. due to an upgrade from R 4.1.0 or other installations, de-installation of the suspect packages, or just deletion of the user library can help in most cases.

How to do this depends on the operating system.