# I can't install "ggradar"

Tags: r, github

I need to install `ggradar` but I can't. I'm working on R-4.1.1 and the latest version of R Studio.
I tried in two different ways :

1 - `install.packages("ggadar")` and the result :

> Warning in install.packages :   the package ‘ggradar’ is not available
> for this version of R

2- `devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar",dependencies=TRUE)` and the result :

> Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:   Timeout was
> reached: [api.github.com] Connection timed out after 10013
> milliseconds

Comment: We asked you some information as you already asked a similar question here and you did not reply :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614576/cant-install-usethis-package#comment123047211_69614576

Answer (score 2):

You might need the `remote` package first:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar")
```

Comment: My guess is that some dependency is failing to install (like `curl`).

Comment: I just installed the package ````remotes```` and run ````remotes::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar")```` and I have the same error : **Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: [api.github.com] Connection timed out after 10010 milliseconds** .. :(

Comment: If you have another solution..I really need this package :(

Answer (score 0):

First install devtools:

```
install.pakages("devtools")
```

Then paste this command:

```
devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar", dependencies = TRUE)
```

After, completion of install check the library from following command:

```
library(ggradar)
```

If no error is shown, it indicates your installation is successful; else update the IDE and packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems installing `ggradar2`, but updating the package `rlang` worked for me:

1. ```
   install.packages("rlang")
   ```

   Make sure it is the latest version.
2. ```
   devtools::install_github("xl0418/ggradar2",dependencies=TRUE)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to install ggradar.

```r
install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar", INSTALL_opts = c("--with-keep.source", "--install-tests"))
```

I got this code from R help menu.